# GWT - ListBox selected item does not maintain state

Tags: gwt, listbox

I have a GWT ListBox that fills with 70 items. User would scroll the list, say to the bottom and selects an item and clicks on Search button and it will take user to a detail screen with more information.

Anyways, when they press the return arrow on IE and goes back to the main page, this ListBox now displays the top of the list.  If user scrolls all the way down, he will see the highlighted choice he made earlier.

Is there a way set this ListBox to maintain state and shows the previous selection so that user doesn't have to scroll all the way down?  Thank you.

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you tried in other versions? Have you tried in other browsers?

Comment: IE 11 and other browsers

Comment: It seems you are reloading the page. Any widget doesnot retain the state after reloading. You have call setValue() on it manually when the user hits the return arrow

Comment: Not sure if the page reloads because if I scroll down in that ListBox, I still see the row highlighted from previous click.  Wouldn't that row be deselected if the page reloads?